# Назначение строк

Tags: python, paramiko

Мне необходимо отредактировать чужой код на Python, но у меня небольшой опыт программирования, и в том коде есть две строки не очень мне понятные:

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file('/tmp/paramiko.log')
paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
```

Для чего необходимы эти строки?

Подключаемые модули:

```
import os
import datetime
import time
import paramiko
import sys
import shutil
from os import listdir
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: Просто по названиям функций: 1 - для записи лога в файл. 2 - для загрузки ssh ключей из указанного файла

Comment: А что за функция util?

Comment: util - сокращение от utilite или utilites, какой-то пакет со служебными объектами/функциями. Рекомендую почитать документацию paramiko, чтобы не гадать, что есть что.

Comment: Хотя конкретно про util я в документации на https://docs.paramiko.org ничего не вижу, значит придется смотреть сам файл https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/paramiko/util.py и прогонять через переводчик строки документации в функциях в коде (то что заключено в тройные кавычки `"""`)